# Real quadratic spaces and rational quadratic spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

Let's say we have two invertible symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ with same size and same discriminants. (det($A$)/det($B$) is a square of some rational number)

One problem asks me to give an example of this $A$ and $B$ such that the real quadratic spaces constructed by them are isomorphic but the rational quadratic spaces constructed by them are not isomorphic.

I tried several types but can't express such difference: is there any trick to do this?

Comment: what book are you using?

Comment: I use Artin's algebra. But this question doesn't have relation to (or at least has no direct relation) my book. All the information I have is here. Basically, I want to ask, what kind of Q1 Q2 can let their spaces on Field R be isomorphic but the same on Field Rational Number be otherwise.